# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException, How to fix the error?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am currently studying Spring DI.

But I have not been able to run the project due to some error.

Below is a list of errors.

Exception in thread "main"

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext.load(GenericXmlApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext.<init>(GenericXmlApplicationContext.java:69)
    at Spring_DI.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:15)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
```

The following is the contents of applicationContext.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="cats" class="Spring_DI.Cats" />
<!-- "Spring_DI.MyCats"클래스를 myCats라는 id를 지정해서 객체(bean)을 생성 -->
<bean id="myCats" class="Spring_DI.MyCats">
    <!-- Spring_DI.Cats.MyCats라는 클래스에 있는 필드들의 값을 설정해줌 -->
    <property name="cats"><!-- 첫번째 property(필드) -->
        <ref bean="cats"/><!-- 이 property는 위에서 생성한 bean(객체)인 cats를 참조한다. -->
    </property>
    <property name="firstCatName" value="순덕" /><!-- MyCats의 필드의 이름과 값을 설정 -->
    <property name="secondCatName" value="나비" />
    <property name="firstCatAge" value="1" />
    <property name="secondCatAhttps://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tabge" value="2" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Here is the contents of the java file.

```
package Spring_DI;

import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         //bean을 설정한 xml파일이 있는 위치 지정
        String configLocation = "classpath:applicationContext.xml";

        //지정한 위치를 참고하여 설정파일을 얻어옴
        AbstractApplicationContext ctx = 
                new GenericXmlApplicationContext(configLocation);

        //설정파일에서 bean을 가져옴
        //getBean()를 이용해서 MyCats타입에서 myCats를 얻어와서 객체를 생성 
        // = 방법1 예제처럼 직접 생성이 아닌 외부에서 얻어옴(주입을 시켜줌)
        MyCats myCat = ctx.getBean("myCats",MyCats.class);

        //호출
        myCat.catsNameInfo();
        myCat.catsAgeInfo();
    }

}
```

The following is the project structure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzbhC.png)

How can I handle the above error?

And why does the above error occur?

Please let me know how to fix the problem.

Comment: Can you upload your project's directories structure? Where is your applicationContext.xml file? in resource folder?

Comment: I will revise the article based on your question.

Comment: Please check. @Afridi

Comment: Move your applicationContext.xml file from 'Spring_DI' to 'src' folder. Or follow this:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_hello_world_example.htm

Comment: Oh, It is work...!! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the screenshot, your project is maven project. So the resources(any other files than source files) should be placed in src/main/resources.When Maven build your project, it expects to find only Java source files under src/main/java, and ignores all the other files.